# Datatables: I'm getting recordsTotal: 1 and recordsFiltered 0

Tags: php, datatables

I'm getting 1 recordsTotal but 0 recordsFiltered and it says

> Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from 1 total entries)

That 1 filtered entry is what I'm looking for and somehow, I can't see it in my datatables.
I'm pretty sure my queries are correct. It is just a simple where query

```
$search = '%'. str_replace(" ", "%", trim($request->search['value'])) .'%';
            $order_query->where('o.full_name', 'like', $search);
```

I tried putting this

```
$search =   $name = '%Gerald%Sanders%';
            $order_query->where('o.full_name', 'like', $name);
```

And it is returning output just fine. But when I'm using the search function, it is filtering the data that I am getting. Btw, when I typed "Gerald Sanders" in the search box, it will be changed to %Gerald%Sanders% too so I'm sure they are exactly the same (I also tried using if($search === $name) and it is the same)

Comment: Step one would be confirming your values. Have you done that? Step two would be enabling database query logs to see what is being sent to the database.

Comment: Yes, I've done all that. It seems that when the code 

$out = Datatables::of($order_query)->make(true); 

executes, the data return by my query was not being included.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using Yajra Datatables. I'm having the same issue and when I add this optiion, it works. Actually, I don't know why :). Hope this helps you too

```
$out = Datatables::of($order_query)
                   ->skipAutoFilter()  
                   ->make(true);
```